# how do i use right string charset encoding for sending strings from dao to jsp and show it?

Tags: java, spring, jsp, utf-8, dao

product model :

```
public class product {
    private String productName;
    private String productCategory;
    private String productDescription;
    private double productPrice;
    private String productCondition;
    private String productStatus;
    private int unitInStatus;
    private String productManufacturer;
```

getter and setters
.
.
.

DAO:

```
String myString="عروسک خرس";
    byte[] ptext=myString.getBytes("UTF-8");
    String out=new String(ptext,"UTF-8");
    product1.setProductName(out);


    product1.setProductCategory("عروسک");
    product1.setProductDescription("عرسک پول?ش? قابل شستشو");
```

jsp :

```
<td>${product.productName}</td>
   <td>${product.productCategory}</td>
   <td>${product.productCondition}</td>
   <td>${product.productPrice}</td>
```

result :

```
نام محصول   دسته    شریایظ  (تومان) قیمت
���Ә ���    ���Ә    ��?�    15000.0
```

Comment: What does product.productCondition looks like in the DAO? You showed the other fields but not this one? Can you edit your question?

Comment: product is a model and product condition is one its fields

Comment: What is the purpose of converting string to UTF-8 and then back to string in the DAO???

Comment: I wrote it to tell others that it's not the answer, cause somebody consider it as the answer while it has no effect

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is related to the os.i changed my os from widows to linux

Answer (score 0):

One problem can be here:

```
String myString = "عروسک خرس";
```

Here the **editor** must use the same encoding as the **java compiler javac/jspc**. If the file is moved from Windows to Linux (as is mentioned), the default encoding may change.

Check this with u-escaping.

```
String myString = "\u0639\u0631\u0648\u0633"
        + "\u06A9\u0020\u062E\u0631\u0633";
```

Specify the encoding in the project.

The following is not needed

```
byte[] ptext = myString.getBytes("UTF-8");
String out = new String(ptext,"UTF-8");
```